# SCOM Sharepoint Monitoring for SharePoint 2016 : How to install and configure a SCOM to monitor a SharePoint 2016 farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, monitoring, scom

I am looking for explicite examples/documentations/good practices describing the way to install, configure and use SCOM to monitor SharePoint 2016 Farm

Thanks,

Comment: Here is an article for your reference: [Configuring the SharePoint 2013 Management Pack](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kevinholman/2013/05/13/configuring-the-sharepoint-2013-management-pack/)

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of the Scom is not different from previous version of SharePoint. 
You need following things.

1. System Center Operations Manager 2012 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 with Full-Text Search feature are required to run System Center Monitoring Pack for SharePoint 2016.
2. Have System Center Operations Manager 2012 deployed in at least one Management Group.
3. Have the Operations Manager 2012 agent deployed on all computers that you want to monitor.
4. Create a “SharePoint Discovery/Monitoring Account” Run As Account that is associated with a user account that has SharePoint 2016 farm administrative privileges and access to the related databases and application programming interface (API).

Once you have properly installed and configured the SCOM servers then you need to install and configure the **SharePoint 2016 Management Pack** from SCOM on SCOM servers.

Please read the complete Detail on this Blog: [System Center Management Pack for SharePoint Server 2016](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/allthat/2017/03/31/system-center-management-pack-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)

You can download the Management Pack & installation Doc from here: [System Center Management Pack for SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52043) Read the installation doc, they include everything which one required.

P.S: We are using SCOM for our 2016 servers and only thing our SCOM team did with existing SCOM servers are install & configure the New Management Pack.

Answer (score 0):

**For SharePoint 2016,** You should

- Have System Center Operations Manager 2012 deployed in at least one Management Group
- Have the Operations Manager 2012 agent deployed on all servers that you want to monitor.
- Download the [System Center Management Pack for SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=52043)

> The Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016 Management Pack is designed to be
>   used for monitoring SharePoint Server 2016 events,

**Some considerations for the running account**

- Local admin on all SharePoint Front End and Application Servers
- Local admin on all SQL machines that host SharePoint databases
- Full Farm Administrator rights within SharePoint
- DBO for all SharePoint databases

**Below is a good reference, to getting start**

- [System Center Management Pack for SharePoint Server 2016](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/allthat/2017/03/31/system-center-management-pack-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)
- [SCOM: MP for SharePoint Server 2016](http://www.opsman.co.za/scom-mp-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)
- [INSTALL AND CONFIGURE SYSTEM CENTER MANAGEMENT PACK FOR SHAREPOINT SERVER 2013](http://www.ms-opsmgr.eu/?p=1846) (it's considered the same for SP 2016)